# Whatsapp Media attachment not showing new photos after new windows update

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-930, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, attachments

my whatsapp not showing new photos when selecting photos for status or to send as an attachments in nokia lumia 930 after windows 10 recent update. it was working fine as i could send new photos. the photos were displaying in the attachment option and status option normally. but after update it doesn't show the photos that i captured or downloaded or taken as a screenshot after the update. all the old photos are still there and i can select them normally.

I have been using this phone for last 6 months and this is the first time i've encountered this issue. i've searched over the internet but haven't found anyone with the same issue.
Thanks in advance.

OS Build After Update : 10.0.14393.2126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed. what i did is just factory reset my phone and then updated it again to the latest OS build and it just worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Think it's related to OS build. All recent images either taken by camera(Camera Roll) or those saved from internet (Saved pictures) are not having thumbnails when I explore them by connecting to PC. Also im not able to edit these photos using any app whereas editing old ones happen all right. 
In photos app all looks fine.

Comment: yeah may be. it all happened after the windows update to a new build. before that everything was working fine. i can't even explore the new picture by connecting the phone to the PC. its strange

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is fixed with the new OS build (10.0.14393.2189). After update all back to normal. But those images between the last update still not seen.